# Inserting items into Writing Desk

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mystcraft

I'm not sure how Forge handles the relation between block side and inventory slots, but I would like to auto-refill my Writing Desk, that is, insert paper and ink vials and retrieve empty vials. However, it doesn't matter what side (of the 10 available, two blocks wide), I can only insert the paper. I would like to know what is the side connected to the ink vials inventory slot for this block, and also, if possible, how can I easily determine that for any given block. Finally if there is no association, is there any other way to auto refill my desk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mystcraft Writing does does implement ISidedInventory, but the only slot that is bound to anything is the paper slot, you may be able to use factorization routers to insert/extract bottles.

Comment: Oh, so sad it can't be done... Maybe in the next releases